# Trying to add Done button to the dropdown and making stick to the bottom of material ui select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to add Done button to the drop-down and making stick to the bottom of material UI Select. Actually it work but i have a problem with the onchange in Select component. Here is the code Fyi

```
 <Select
  value={formState.roles.value}
  className={classes.selectField}
  multiple
  onChange={(event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    handleChange(
      'roles',
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value
    );
  }}
  renderValue={() => <></>}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
  <Box height={'200px'} overflow={'auto'}>
    {filteredRoles?.map((value, key) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={key} value={value.roleTitle}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={
              formState.roles.value.indexOf(
                value.roleTitle ?? ''
              ) > -1
            }
          />
          <ListItemText primary={value.roleTitle} />
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </Box>
  <Box
    sx={{
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
    }}
  >
    <Button
      size="small"
      variant="contained"
      sx={{ float: 'right' }}
    >
      Done
    </Button>
  </Box>
</Select>
```

I have tried done button with the above code, UI wise it looks fine but not able to trigger the Select onChange because of wrapping Box across the MenuItem.
So is there any other way which works